# How to bind event to window root dynamically?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to bind resize event? my event broken.

I found weird 2 conditions if i sets condition greater width 600 font-size 5. it will trigger event once only.

the other condition if i sets font-size to 12. no event trigger.

style.py

```
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Style(ttk.Style):
    _window = None

    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)
        self._window = window

        self.configure("USERINFO.TLabel", font=('script', 12))

        self._window.bind("<Configure>", self.__resize)
    
    def __resize(self, event):
        if event.width > 600:
            self.configure("USERINFO.TLabel", font=('Helvetica', 5))          
        else:
            self.configure("USERINFO.TLabel", font=('script', 12))
```

guy.py

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from style import Style

class MainWindow(tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        Style(self)

        self._clientarea()
    
    def _clientarea(self):
        frame = ttk.Frame(self).grid(column=0, row=0)
        ttk.Label(frame, text="Username: ", style="USERINFO.TLabel").grid(column=0, row=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As you bind the event on the root window, so the callback will be triggered when its child widgets are resized.  You can verify it by adding `print(event.widget)` inside `__resize()`.  So you need to do the changing of style only when `event.widget` is `self._window`.

Comment: try changing `event.width > 600` to `self._window.winfo_width() > 600`, also your frame will return `None` since it has inline `grid`.